# Problema na interface de edição do layout XML do android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.karlo.menu"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image: Edição do XML]

Boa tarde.
Eu não estou conseguindo usar o editor do layout XML no android studio. Aparece isso e não consigo arrastar os campos de texto ou configurar as distancias e alinhamento. Acho muito mais intuitivo fazer usando esse editor do que editar digitar o código mesmo. 
Alguém já passou por isso? Ou poderia me ajudar a resolver o problema ? 
Desde já agradeço.
[image: Versão do Android studio]

Comment: Poderia adicionar o seu build.gradle (app)?

Comment: Adicionei ali em cima

Comment: Tente colocar outro tema de exibição, na tela que você postou acima está "NoActionBar" tente colocar outro como "Material.Light".

Comment: Deu certo mudei ali em cima